# Dedicated worker cache role stuck in busy only when using virtual network

Tags: caching, azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-caching

I have an Azure service that contains a dedicated cache worker role.

When a NetworkConfiguration section is added to the cscfg file, which specifies our virtual network, the cache role does not start and is stuck as "Busy". I can't access any info from the cache role (either by Intellitrace or azure diagnostic logs) since it looks like the role itself never starts up.

When the NetworkConfiguration section is removed, the cache role starts fine.

Has anyone have run into a similar issue or have any tips on resolving this?

The storage accounts that is used for the cache role is on the affinity group connected to the virtual network.

The network config we use is here:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
<Dns>
  <DnsServers>
    <DnsServer name="DNSServer" IPAddress="10.10.0.2" />
  </DnsServers>
</Dns>
<VirtualNetworkSite name="Prod" />
<AddressAssignments>
  <InstanceAddress roleName="CacheRole">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="Subnet" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
  <InstanceAddress roleName="Precacher">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="Subnet" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
  <InstanceAddress roleName="Management">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="Subnet" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
</AddressAssignments>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you made any progress on this?  I have a similar issue, but my cloud service uses the distributed cache across all my instances, instead of a dedicated role.  I have a worker and a web role, and when I add the network config lines in the cscfg, the deployment gets stuck in a busy statement.  I can verify that it did assign IP addresses in the subnet, as the Vnet dashboard shows my instances and their newly assigned IP addresses.  Also, I should mention that I don't have the <Dns> section, as I'm hoping to rely on Azure for DNS.